# Cant login to newly cloned HyperV server

Tags: hyper-v

I have a VM running on HyperV in production. I'm trying to clone that server to a smaller host so I can do testing, etc.

I set the local administrator password on the VM so I would be sure I had it correct.
Also, the domain administrator password should be cached.

I've exported the VM, copied the files over to the new server, created a new VM, attached the hard drive.

When I start the VM, I think it doesn't connect to the network since it gets an IP of 169.254.254.xxx, even though the settings show that it has access to the network card.
The server starts up fine, but neither the domain admin or the local admin can log in.

I'm not sure where to go next. Feels like I need to log in to fix the network access and need network access to be able to log in.

Also, it appears that it still thinks it has the original name, SRV-APP2, as that is the machine it says I'm logging in to with .\administrator, even though I gave it a different name in HyperV.
I can't RDP into the machine or Ping. Only connect through the HyperV Manager.

Comment: Is the cloned host on the same network segment or VLAN? It's possible a duplicate IP address is causing some of these problems. Try disconnecting the virtual NIC before starting up the VM perhaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you exported the VM, why didn't you just import it? The exported VM will include the configuration file with all of the VM settings. Exporting the VM and then attaching the virtual hard drive to a new VM kind of defeats the purpose of exporting it.
2. Make sure the new VM is connected to an external virtual switch and that the external virtual switch is connected to the physical network.
3. Of course the VM has the same computer name. It's an export of the original VM. Exporting the VM doesn't change the identity of the VM. If you want to change the identity of the VM then you need to sysprep it before exporting it or rename the computer after importing the VM.
4. The fact that the VM is getting an APIPA address tells me that it has no access to a DHCP server or that you don't have a DHCP server.
5. Try disconnecting or removing the virtual NIC for the VM and see if you can log on. So long as Windows detects a network connection you won't be able to log on with cached credentials. Disconnecting the VM from the network should resolve that and allow you to then log onto the VM.

Comment: It sounds like my best bet is to turn off the network card so it can't reach the network and run into a conflict. Then my local login should work and I can reset the name and the IP.

Comment: "If you exported the VM, why didn't you just import it?" We initially did that, but since the QA machine is smaller than the prod machine, it failed. It asked us for those settings when importing, then went ahead and used the originals and failed. If this didn't work, our next step would have been to edit the XML before importing.

Comment: "So long as Windows detects a network connection you won't be able to log on with cached credentials." This turned out to be a key point that led to the solution and the reason I marked this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to wrap this up for whoever runs into this situation next, we tried a lot of things and finally got it to work.
I believe that the key steps were:

1. Disconnect from the network. We pulled the ethernet cord from the host machine when we couldn't get in otherwise. Not sure if this was really required, but it worked.
   Once we were isolated from the network, we could log in using the cached credentials.
2. Once in, we changed the machine name and the fixed IP.
3. Reconnect to the network. This didn't appear to work at first, but it turned out we had missed something in the network setup.

Overall, I can't say that we got an "answer" from the forum, but what we did get was immensely valuable - encouragement that we were going the right direction, that we weren't crazy, that what we were doing *should* work, and that gave us the confidence to keep after it and eventually led to getting everything working.

Thanks!